# Jenkins XML api - how to read text contents of jenkins master page?

Tags: java, jenkins, xml-parsing

I need to read some text on Jenkins master page, under which several jobs are listed, although as its not the job, I am not able to find any text information on that page except the job names after its xml view, its kind of convenience message printed for user which I need to read.

I tried to get xml view of the page as below :

```
http://{jenkinsserver}/api/xml
```

Instead if I try to do same for a job listed under this server I can see text information on its xml view.

```
http://{jenkinsserver}/view/job/{jobname}/api/xml
```

Is there any I can read that information ?

Comment: What information are you trying to read? If it's not in the XML API, then perhaps you need to scrape the page itself.

Comment: @DaveBacher I want to read the message that "Jenkins is going to shutdown" and then stop giving further builds it this message there on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Jenkins is going to shut down, then the *quietingDown* field is set to true in the main page's API response.

Comment: thanks for your answer, for information where I can get more detailed information about such fields and general jenkins xml api ?